# With nginx, automatically redirect /forums, /forums/*, and /forum to -> /forum/*?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, nginx, http-status-code-301

I have a forum at /forum/.  My nginx sites-available/ config file has a bunch of logic to rewrite requests once they're at /forum/*.  But, I don't know how to do a 301 redirect such that:

/forum
/forums/
and /forums/*

will all point to /forum/, or to /forum/.  (if appropriate).

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
rewrite ^/forum$    /forum/? permanent;
rewrite ^/forums/.* /forum/? permanent;
```

Though I don't really understand what you mean by "or to /forum/. (if appropriate)". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: As in the file copy syntax: cp [filename] directory/.

Comment: `cp filename directory/.` is the same as `cp filename directory/`. I still don't understand if you really need something else to happen when you redirect from `/forums/something_more` instead of just `/forums/`, but I guess you don't.